# Display order items names in WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to display order_item of order in admin list like in this screenshot:

[image]

Changing 
`/woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php` file, I tried to add the following:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$ss = $product->get_name();


echo $ss
echo $product->get_name();
echo get_the_title($product_id); // this one display the order date
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: is it possible to add an thumbnail image of the product as well?

Comment: @G-MAN I added a solution with image product for you ;-) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never overwrite core files!** for many reasons. Note that an order can have many items (products).

On orders admin list, the following will add item(s) *(product(s))* names, to order status column:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $the_order, $post;

    if ( 'order_status' === $column ) {
        $products_names = []; // Initializing

        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $the_order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object
            $products_names[]  = $item->get_name(); // Store in an array
        }
        // Display
        echo '<ul style="list-style: none;"><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $products_names) . '</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: It is placed before the old content !!  
It is possible to place after?  Please...

Comment: @webmastx do you think about a new column between "status" and "billing" ? In this case, it will be difficult because you will get a different number of "<td>" (columns) compared to "<th>" (headers). This could help you add a new column : https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-woocommerce-orders-list-column/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on @loictheaztec with CSS styling and quantity of each product displayed.

[image: product items preview in wp woo order list]

Add the following code to `function.php` :

```php
// hook for order items preview
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $the_order, $post;

    if ( 'order_status' === $column ) {
                
        // Start list
        echo '<ul class="orders-list-items-preview">';
        
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $the_order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product      = $item->get_product();
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $product_qty  = $item->get_quantity();
            echo "<li><label>$product_qty</label> $product_name</li>";
        }
        
        // End list
        echo '</ul>';

    }
}

// CSS for order items preview
add_action('admin_head', 'orders-list-preview-css');
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo "<style>
    .orders-list-items-preview {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 8px 8px 0 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .orders-list-items-preview li {
        padding-left: 45px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .orders-list-items-preview li label {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 25px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
        left: 5px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
  </style>";
}
```

**EDIT : Solution added with product image (and quantity moved on right)**

[image]

```php
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'orders_list_preview_items', 20, 2 );
function orders_list_preview_items($column, $post_id) {
    
    global $the_order, $post;
    
    if ('order_status' === $column) {
        
        // Start list
        echo '<ul class="orders-list-items-preview">';
        
        // Loop through order items
        foreach($the_order->get_items() as $item) {
            
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $img     = wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id());
            
            $name    = $item->get_name();
            $qty     = $item->get_quantity();
            
            echo "<li>
                <img src=\"$img\" />
                <label>$qty</label> $name
            </li>";
        }
        
        // End list
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    
    
}


add_action('admin_head', 'orders_list_preview_css');
function orders_list_preview_css() {
  echo "<style>
    .orders-list-items-preview {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 8px 8px 0 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .orders-list-items-preview li {
        padding-left: 55px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-right: 40px;
        padding-top: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 11px;
        min-height: 30px;
    }
    .orders-list-items-preview li label {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 25px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
        right: 5px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    .orders-list-items-preview img {
        margin: 1px 2px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 30px;
        max-height: 30px !important;
    }
  </style>";
}
```